# What is the solution name to provide in Azure DevOps while exporting the solution for Dynamics 365 Field service?

Tags: azure-devops, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am very new to Microsoft Dynamics 365 and facing some issue while running the build.I have setup Build pipeline in Azure DevOps for Dynamics 365 Field service application and Added the export solution task and configured the Connection string in the export solution task but I have no idea of what is the solution name I have to provide to export the solution. I am not sure whether I miss anything or since I am new to dynamics365 I might be wrong in setting up the pipeline in azure DevOps. Could you please help me with the solution please.Highly appreciated of you could provide the solution and help me to understand the concepts. Please find the attached screenshot below.[image: Azure DevOps Error]

Comment: If you want to export a solution you need to have created a solution at some earlier point and that's the name you need to provide to the export task you are trying to configure. It looks like you already have a *"Publish Customizations"* task where this information might also be available.

Comment: Actually I didn't create any solution yet.May be I missed to create it.I am doing this first time and I am not aware of this stuff.Could you please explain where I need to create the solution is it .net solution or I need to create solution in dynamics365 site ? Kindly help me on this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Build Pipeline Tasks you are using - all I can do is confirm that indeed you need a solution in Dynamics 365. This solution serves as a container for the assets you want to export - in essence it is just a .zip file.

Comment: @PDBRPraveen any followup questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I researched for the solution,I got the solution by myself.The solution name is nothing but the name of the solution we need to create in CRM instance of dynamics 365 .

Step 1: log into the CRM instance ( https://YOURNAME.crm8.dynamics.com/main.aspx?forceUCI=1&pagetype=apps ) .

Step 2: Go to the Advances settings under settings option on the right side top corner.

Step 3: It will redirect you to settings page ( https://YOURNAME.crm8.dynamics.com/main.aspx?**settingsonly**=true#882394659 ). Select the settings tab (Drop Down) again and you can see the customization category and there you can click on solutions.Here you can see the list of solutions already created by someone.

Step 4: Here is the step to create your own solution and configure in Azure DevOps task while exporting and importing.

Answer (score 0):

We used to give sprint name or hotfix with sequential number which is unique.

Ex. Sprint202001 or Hotfix202001

> [image]